# Why does ``totally ramified'' lift as a property?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Write $D_n$ for $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)}$. Let $\ell$ be an odd prime and $m$ an integer with $\ell \equiv 1 \text{ mod } m$.

**Question: Why is the following true?**

If the prime ideal factorisation of $\ell D_m$ is $$\ell D_m= \prod_i \lambda_i^{r_i},$$
then the prime ideal factorisation of $\ell D_{m \ell}$ is $$\ell D_{m \ell}= \prod_{i} L_i^{r_i (\ell-1)},$$

***and we have*** $\lambda D_{m \ell}= L^{\ell-1}$.

That is, $\lambda$ is totally ramified (and $\ell$ is).

---

Supposedly this has something to do with $\ell D_\ell=(1-\zeta_\ell)^{\ell-1}D_\ell= \mu^{\ell-1} D_\ell$.

That is, we have $$\ell D_{m \ell}=\ell D_\ell D_{m \ell}= (\mu D_{m\ell})^{\ell-1}= \left(\prod_{i}P_i\right)^{\ell-1}$$

with $P_i \subset D_{m \ell}$ prime ideals, and $$\ell D_{m \ell}=\ell D_m D_{m \ell}= \prod_i \lambda_i^{r_i} D_{m \ell}.$$

Though I cannot see how to attain the result from this.

Also it might be useful that all the $r_i$ are equal (see the ``splitting of prime ideals in Galois extensions'' Wiki page). Also, all the $\lambda_i$ are Galois conjugates.

Comment: Am I being foolish to expect subscripts on your $L$?

Comment: @Lubin No, you aren't.

Comment: @Lubin If you're interested, my confusion basically arises from trying to understand the last sentence of the 2nd paragraph of http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~kartikp/teaching/678-Fall2009/L9.pdf.

Comment: I’m afraid this is a little far from whatever expertise I have. I can’t promise to look at this more deeply, so I wish you good luck.